# Error XLS file generate and open using html,php

Tags: php, codeigniter, xls

I have generate xls file using html and php everthing is fine.
But problem is that when tring to open file then following error display

[image: error display whene open]

My code is here:

```
    $filename = "file.xls";
    header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
    header("Content-type:   application/x-msexcel; charset=utf-8");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=".$filename); //tell browser what's the file name
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
    echo '<table>
               <tr>
                   <th>heading1</th>
                   <th>heading2</th>
                   <th>heading3</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>data1</td>
                   <td>data2</td>
                   <td>data3</td>
               </tr>
           </table>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the data you are writing to it. Excel expects a properly formatted file if saving as an `.xls`. You have to write explicit data reserved to Excel and not just HTML tables.

In order to prevent the popup error window, save your file as `.csv` and not `.xls`.

`.xls` files are **"binary"** files, as opposed to the data you wish to enter which is **"text-based"**. That is why Excel prompts you when opening the file.

You could even save it with an `.html` extension, that will work also, I tried it.

One of the libraries you could use is called PHPExcel and can be found at the following URL:

- http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: `.xls` files are **"binary"** files, as opposed to the data you wish to enter which is **"text-based"**. That is why Excel prompts you when opening the file. You could look into http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ which may help you.

Comment: thank's for answer @Fred -ii- i have now create with **PHPExcel**

Comment: @chavdamalde You're welcome. If you feel your question has been answered, then please click the checkmark to accept.

Comment: @chavdamalde It has been added.